# Why is General sibling combinator not always working?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

I have four divs, and i want to change their width and height on hover so the one you are hovering over expands and all others shrink for how much hovered one expanded. I managed to get it working when i hover over first div, but when i try to do the same with other three nothing happens.
My HTML:

```
<div  id="main">
        <div  id="mainOne">
            <h3>text</h3>
        </div>
        <div  id="mainTwo">
            <h3>text2</h3>
        </div>
        <div  id="mainThree">
            <h3>text3</h3>
        </div>
        <div  id="mainFour">
            <h3>text4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
/* HOVER 1 */

#mainOne:hover{
width:748px;
height:600px;
}

#mainOne:hover + #mainTwo{
width:248px;
height: 600px;
}

#mainOne:hover ~ #mainThree{
height:200px;
}
#mainOne:hover ~ #mainFour{
height:200px;
}

/* END HOVER 1 */

/* HOVER 2 */
#mainTwo:hover{
width:748px;
height:600px;
}

#mainTwo:hover + #mainOne{
width:248px;
height: 600px;
}
#mainTwo:hover + #mainThree{
height:200px;
}
#mainTwo:hover ~ #mainFour{
height:200px;
}

/* END HOVER 2 */
```

So when i hover over mainOne, everything changes, but when i hover over mainTwo just mainTwo changes and messes up everything else. What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS can only ([currently](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)) target elements that appear *later* in the DOM, therefore `#mainTwo + #mainThree` will work, but `#mainTwo + #mainOne` cannot.

To target previous siblings you'd have to wrap the siblings within another, parent, element and then style the previous siblings based on the hover of that parent.

```
div > div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #f00;
}

#main:hover > div {
    width: 50%;
}

#main:hover > div:hover ~ div {
    width: 50%;
}

#main:hover > div:hover {
    width: 80%;
}
```

[JS fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xVT8Y/)

Comment: I now understand what the problem is, and i noticed that now Everything shrinks but mainOne, because it is before mainTwo, but looks like this solution is a bit too complex for me, so I'll take my time to understand it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

All your `mainTwo` rules with `:hover` use the adjacent sibling combinator.

Only `#mainTwo + #mainThree`  can match as neither `#mainOne` or `#mainFour` are the next sibling to `#mainTwo`.

If you used the general sibling combinator (`~`) then you could match `#mainFour` too.

Since `#mainOne` **precedes** `#mainTwo`, you can't match it with a rule that depends on the existence of `#mainTwo`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed combinators, but i still get the same result.